# What are do's and don'ts on published APK for alpha and beta testing and how to manage it in Google Play for developers?

Tags: publishing, google-play, alpha, beta, test-driven-development

Before the official public release or publishing the first prototype game, I learned about alpha and beta testing in order to gain feedback and fixes needed to improve or correct the game's system. I have some several questions regarding this feature on development feature on Google Play where game developers can publish games:

- *Is it okay include the actual ad banner display (via AdMob) on game screen during publishing for alpha or beta testing in Google Play developer section?*
- *My alpha version is published but why I can't see the published app on Google Play store? I set it for open alpha testing, with only 1,000-1,500 random users.*
- *After I published for the alpha testing, I tried [**this link**](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.bodapps.tongits) download it via different user but it appeared nothing (even the URL to the APK install download) except the main Gmail account I used as my main source for collecting feedback and as a username to gain access to Google Play Developer. How will ensure to other users to download and test the app during open alpha testing version via invite links?*
- *Lastly, whatever the APK version no. for alpha would be the same for beta and official release or not?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I'm aware there's no restriction on whether or not you can show ads in alpha/beta apps - the fact that it's alpha/beta only limits who can download it, and nothing else
2. Only apps that are in production can be found via searching on the Google Play Store - if it's in open alpha/beta then people need to have the testing link (the one in your 3rd point) to be able to download it, and if it's in closed alpha/beta then people have to join the appropriate Google+ community and have the testing link. Seeing as your app is in open alpha, the only way for people to download your app is for you to give them the testing link
3. That link works fine for me, so I'm not sure what the problem is I'm afraid
4. It's fine to have the same version number - just promote the app from alpha/beta to production via the Google Play Developer Console

Comment: For #2, that doesn't seem to be the case, I can find my alpha via incognito searching the playstore, or via google, bing and duckduckgo. Not sure why that is though, since the docs corroborate what you've written.